# Is there a way to change the particles from the second item on a keyed particle animation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, keyframes

I have a keyed particle system with three objects, 1 controller and 2 items. Item A turns its particles into item B, and the three items share the same particle system, so it works, **but** the item B starts its animation before (since it has the same animation as the item A). What I need is that the item B is invisible and begins to appear thanks to the particles given from item A.

Is this possible? *Even if I hide the emitter (Item B) it still appears forming the particles.*

Comment: Did you try unchecking `Camera` under `Ray Visibility`?

Comment: Also, your question is a little unclear. Could you clarify the content and title?

Comment: I don't know how to really explain it since i'm new in the particle systems, i'll upload a video of the problem.

Comment: Ok, already uploaded the video, 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/gygw1uc086mxrn8/clip0002.avi?dl=0
i have the letter ''L'' the item A is the one from the left, and the item B the one from the right, the item A fills the item B with particles and that's what i want, but the item B starts before, since they both share exactly the same particle system, and if i change the item B particle system, the keyed animation is lost...
What i want (taking off all the technical things) is to form a letter (with particles) from 0, but still having this kind of animation, since i need it for making something later.

Comment: Looks like you don't have nearly enough particles :-(

Comment: But if i add more? i'll create the form, but how do i hide the first emitter and also make the second item start from 0? (with that i mean that i want the 2nd item to start thanks to the particles of the first one, not by itself like in the video)

Comment: Let us [**continue this discussion in chat**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19863/discussion-between-noviceindisguise-and-beavoru).